# Android : Determine direction of hand movement, the curve.

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I am working on an Android project in which I would like to detect hand movement of the user. I looked up a lot of examples, but all the examples only detect changes which are linear, like hand moves up or down, right or left... Nothing I could find for a **curved** detection. I have basic code now, where I am sending the sensor data to our system, but I would directly like to send the curve movement in some object or other interpretation. Being new to this, no idea how to proceed. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot. :-)

Code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sensorMan = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccel = 0.00f;
    mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
    mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        mGravity = event.values.clone();
        // Shake detection
        float x = mGravity[0];
        float y = mGravity[1];
        float z = mGravity[2];
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
        // Make this higher or lower according to how much
        // motion you want to detect
        if(mAccel > 2){
            SensorModel sensorModel = new SensorModel(x,y,z);
            new sendDataToServer().execute(sensorModel);
        }
    }
}

public class sendDataToServer extends AsyncTask<SensorModel,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(SensorModel... params) {
        try {
            SensorModel sensorModel = params[0];
            RestTemplate restTemplate = StaticRestTemplate.getRest();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.postForObject(transmitUrl,sensorModel,Boolean.class);
        }catch (Exception ignored){}

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorMan.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorMan.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Thank you. :-)